# SQL: I need to format a Select Distinct Statement with a Case as one of the values

Tags: sql, oracle, format

So I'm trying to select the distinct operators from a table with a time component that is formatted like this: 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM.'

The logic is this:

```
(if C_StartTime >= date(C_StartTime) + 6:00:00 AM 
AND C_StartTime < date(C_StartTime) + 5:59:59AM 
then C_StartTime,'MM/DD/YYYY' 
ELSE (C_StartTime,'MM/DD/YYYY')-1)
AS DateOnly
```

I can select distinct operators right now but they sign in and out a few times a day so the time is different. It should be noted that "Today" at this company is 3/13/19 6:00:00 AM to 3/14/19 5:59:59 AM.

Below is the final code I tried executing

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT (
    (
      CASE WHEN C_StartTime >= date(C_StartTime) +.25
         AND C_StartTime < date(C_StartTime) +.9999 
         THEN date(C_StartTime) 
         ELSE date(C_StartTime) -1
    ) as DateOnly,
    C_operator,
    C_operatorname,
    C_WorkCentreName
    FROM
      OPERATORTABLE
    WHERE
      .....
```

EDIT>>>>>>

[This is what I get.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IlE4.png)

[This is what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNDqA.png)

I'm Looking for the operator number, the operator name, and the date only (with the knowledge that 1/4/2019 5:59:00 AM = 1/3/2019

Comment: Note that `DISTINCT` is **not a function**, it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` and applies to the whole selected rows. Skip those extra parentheses to make code clearer, i.e. do `SELECT DISTINCT CASE...`

Comment: Please don't paste pictures, use formatted code instead.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I'm sorry, I'm using this to pull the data I need in PowerBi and from a oracle based DB so there really isn't an "output" in a code format as you would normally expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're probably after something like `trunc(c_starttime - 6/24) + 6/24` to get the day to start at 6am instead of midnight:

```
WITH dts AS (SELECT to_date('13/03/2019 05:59:59', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') dt FROM dual UNION ALL
             SELECT to_date('13/03/2019 06:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') dt FROM dual UNION ALL
             SELECT to_date('13/03/2019 06:00:01', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') dt FROM dual UNION ALL
             SELECT to_date('14/03/2019 05:59:59', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') dt FROM dual UNION ALL
             SELECT to_date('14/03/2019 06:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') dt FROM dual)
SELECT dt,
       dt - 6/24 adj_dt,
       TRUNC(dt - 6/24) trunc_adj_dt,
       TRUNC(dt - 6/24) + 6/24 adj_start_of_dt
FROM   dts;

DT                  ADJ_DT              TRUNC_ADJ_DT        ADJ_START_OF_DT
------------------- ------------------- ------------------- -------------------
13/03/2019 05:59:59 12/03/2019 23:59:59 12/03/2019 00:00:00 12/03/2019 06:00:00
13/03/2019 06:00:00 13/03/2019 00:00:00 13/03/2019 00:00:00 13/03/2019 06:00:00
13/03/2019 06:00:01 13/03/2019 00:00:01 13/03/2019 00:00:00 13/03/2019 06:00:00
14/03/2019 05:59:59 13/03/2019 23:59:59 13/03/2019 00:00:00 13/03/2019 06:00:00
14/03/2019 06:00:00 14/03/2019 00:00:00 14/03/2019 00:00:00 14/03/2019 06:00:00
```

I've selected the adj_dt and trunc_adj_dt columns so that you can see how the adj_start_of_dt column was calculated from the original dt column.

You may not need to output 6am on the start date column, so you can skip that (i.e. it's trunc_adj_dt that is the column you'd be after in that case).

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT CASE 
         WHEN C_StartTime >= trunc(c_starttime - 6/24) + 6/24
         AND C_StartTime < trunc(c_starttime - 6//24) + 23.9999/24
         THEN trunc(c_starttime - 6/24)  
         ELSE trunc(c_starttime - 6/24) -1
     as DateOnly,
    C_operator,
    C_operatorname,
    C_WorkCentreName
….. Still getting an error?

Comment: I think you're after `select distinct trunc(c_starttime - 6/24) dateonly, c_operator, ...`

Comment: I have to evaluate if the start time falls into our "day", from 6am this morning to 5:59am the following morning. Any time in there would be considered today. There might be an instance of a start time say at 5:00am on 3/13/19 but that would actually be 3/12/19. I need to look at all the start times and evaluate by that rule. The result is the custom day in the MM/DD/YY format along with operator and yadda yadda. I've been pulling my hair out over it.

Comment: That’s what `trunc(c_starttime - 6/24)` gives you! Think about it: take 6 hours away from 5am on 13th March 2019; that gives 23:00 on 12th March 2019. Truncate that to midnight gives you 12th March 2019 00:00:00. I personally would add the 6 hours back on that to give the day start time as 6am on the relevant date, but YMMV. Seriously, give it a go; I haven’t provided this answer for the goodness of my own health! 

Comment: Very cool, I think I get it now. It's simple because no matter the time, assuming the threshold of the next "day" hasn't passed, then you'll always get the "day" required using the formula that you listed. Thank you! Declare the above as the answer and I'll mark it!

Comment: It’s already in my answer? I gave you sample input data and the output (the trunc_adj_dt or adj_start_of_dt column outputs the start date, with or without the reset back to 6am).